Un problema con un gráfico apilado, agrupado y facetado en ggplot
Estoy intentando crear un gráfico. Aquí está el código para los datos:
ea3 <- ddply(dias_semana, c("mes","weekday", "member_casual", "rideable_type"), summarise, n = sum(n))

ea3$rideable_type <- factor(ea3$rideable_type, levels = c("classic_bike", "electric_bike"))

ea3$fill_var <- factor(interaction(ea3$member_casual, ea3$rideable_type), 
                      levels = c("casual.classic_bike", "casual.electric_bike",
                                "member.classic_bike", "member.electric_bike"))

Y aquí está el código ggplot.
theme_set(theme_bw(base_size = 12))
plot_diassem_m_mc = ggplot(ea3, aes(x=factor(weekday, 
                                   level = c("lunes","martes","miércoles", 
                                             "jueves","viernes","sábado",
                                             "domingo")), y = n, fill=fill_var)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge(), width = 0.7)+
  theme(plot.title=element_text(size=11))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())+
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=10))+
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=8))+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
  labs(title = "Gráfico 11. Número de viajes por cada día de la semana, según mes",
       x = "",
       y = "")+
  facet_wrap(~mes)+
  theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 7, color = "dark green"))+
  theme(legend.key.height= unit(0.2, 'cm'),
        legend.key.width= unit(0.3, 'cm'),
        legend.text = element_text(size=9))+
  scale_fill_discrete(labels=c('casuales (bici clásica)', 'casuales (bici eléctrica)', 
                               'miembros (bici clásica)', 'miembros (bici eléctrica)'))
print(plot_diassem_m_mc)

Este es el gráfico que resulta:

En este gráfico, tenemos 12 meses. En cada mes hay cuatro barras para cada día de la semana. Las cuatro barras del extremo izquierdo tienen valores para el lunes y las del extremo derecho son para el domingo. Las otras pertenecen a los días intermedios. Entonces, quiero dos barras en lugar de cuatro. Una barra para casual y la otra para member (columna member_casual). Luego, quiero dividir cada barra en dos partes: una para las bicicletas clásicas y otra para las bicicletas eléctricas (cada parte debe tener un color diferente). Al final, quiero un gráfico con dos barras para cada día de la semana, y cada barra debe tener dos colores diferentes debido a la división de bicicleta clásica y eléctrica.
Por favor, les pido ayuda con esto. Gracias de antemano.
